# Generics double standard

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Boxcar<S extends Things> {
public ArrayList<S> contents = new ArrayList<S>(); //an arraylist of things

public static void main(String [] args){
    Boxcar test = new Boxcar();
    test.addContents(new Person("239-235-2535", "Ronald", 36)); //works 100%
}

public Boxcar(Things type, int maxElements){
    this.type = type;
    boxcarId = boxcarIdCount;
    boxcarIdCount++;
    this.maxElements = maxElements;
}

public void addContents(S thing) {
    contents.add(thing);
  }
...

}//end boxcar class

public class Person implements Things {
int age;
String govtId, name;

public Person(String govtId, String name, int age){
    this.govtId = govtId;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}//end Consrtructor

public void load(ArrayList<Boxcar<?>> train){
    Person dude = new Person("239-235-235", "Ronald", 36);
    train.get(i).addContents(dude); // won't compile
}
...
}//end Person class

public interface Things {

public void load(ArrayList<Boxcar<?>> train, String [] params);

}//end interface Things

public class Train {
ArrayList<Boxcar<?>> train = new ArrayList<Boxcar<?>>(); 

    public void load(Things thing, String [] params){
    thing.load(train, params);
}
...
}
```

in the code above, the method addContents seems to work fine when executed in the Boxcar class. However when called exactly the same way from the Person class, it behaves differently.

What is the cause for this and how do I fix it?

Comment: It looks like the `Person` class won't compile because perhaps it's not implementing `Things.load`, which takes 2 parameters: `ArrayList<Boxcar<?>> train`, and `String[] params`.  What compile errors did you get?

Comment: "exactly the same way" it's not exactly the same. In the first place, you have `Boxcar` (the raw type). In the second place, you have `Boxcar<?>`

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler doesn't allow accessing methods on a reference of an unbound parameterized type, `Boxcar<?>` in your case, because the type is unknown.

You should instead define bounds to the wildcard and use it as follows:

```
public void load(ArrayList<Boxcar<? super Things>> train)
{
    Person dude = new Person("239-235-235", "Ronald", 36);
    train.get(0).addContents(dude); 
}
```

Comment: or more generally: `List<? extends Boxcar<? super Things>>`

Comment: Thanks that's just the help I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The cause it won't compile, is that the `train` parameter is a list of `Boxcar` of an *unknown* type. Effectively, that means the you have `contents` list in it of an undefined type and you're trying to put a `Person` in there, which is not a type safe operation. Imagine what happened if you executed the load method as follows:

```
person.load(new ArrayList<Boxcar<Integer>>());
```

To fix it, you should fix the signature of the method as follows:

```
public void load(ArrayList<Boxcar<? super Things>> train){
...
}
```

Also, you should avoid mixing generics with raw types, like you did in the main method. Instead of:

```
Boxcar test = new Boxcar();
```

You should use:

```
Boxcar<Things> test = new Boxcar<Things>();
```

Otherwise, even though the code compiles (with a warning) it might fail at runtime with a class cast exception.